# Xcode auto layout issues on project load

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints

For a while now I have been coming across this strange issue in Xcode where each time I open an iOS project, some of the views in my storyboard (via interface builder) will complain about "Frame for x will be different at run time". I then choose "update frames" and it fixes itself. So far so good, but closing the project and re-opening it will cause the same warnings to show. Could this be a bug in Xcode? Any ideas as to why this change does not persist when reloading the project?
I am currently using the latest version of Xcode (v7.3.1), but this problem dates back to much earlier versions.

Comment: I don't have that issue, but did you try to make a commit after updating frames ? Or doing CMD-S ?

Comment: Yep, usually do both. What's strange is that this only happens for some views in some view controllers. My only guess would be that the placement of the views themselves is causing some sort of issue.

Comment: @user1959497 This sounds like a bug :/ I don't think there is anything else we could do to help (except contacting Apple).

Comment: Only you use that code or multiple people are using the same source code?

Comment: Only I use the code on one machine.

Comment: yeah i also think its a bug.It all happen after updating ** Xcode**.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly XCode bug.
I used to face this issue in my previous project.

This is how I got rid of it this time:

- Instead of using storyboard sizes like **compact Width regular Height**, try using **Any width Any Height** (wAny hAny)